# How can I add an ID to a JHTML call

Tags: jhtml

I'm trying to add an ID to a link created by JHTML.  Is that possible?  Here's my call, is there some way I can do a `, #myId` as part of the below?

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $displayData['item'], $displayData['params']); ?>
```

Comment: "_Any additinal parameters passed to JHtml::_() will be passed as parameters themselves to the resolved method._" Can you show your method declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to add an attribute to the resulting anchor tag, pass another argument, an array with attributes as keys and their values as values:

```
echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $displayData['item'], $displayData['params'], ['id' => 'myId']);
```